# c# and sql updating the dataset from a button click

Tags: c#, sql

Hi guys i came stuck again. I am wanting to edit a selected row from my datagridview and replace the data from dgv with the new information in the text fields. I have managed to get it to change all the data in the dataset. So what i am asking is for guidance on how to code it so it only edits the selected row.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(String cmdUpdate = @"update Customer set firstName = @firstName, surname = @surname, email = @email, phonenumber = @phone, mobileNumber = @mobile";
    , con);
    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textFirstName.Text;
    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textSurname.Text;
    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textEmail.Text;
    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textPhone.Text;
    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textMobile.Text;
    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerDataSet.Customer[0].ID;

    con.Open();
    da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Customer Edited");
    con.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: What is your `cmdUpdate` looks like?

Comment: Why do you not simply change the datarow in the Dataset and throw that into the Update method of the DataAdapter?

Comment: Ralf i am completely new to this so not sure how to do that. I have been following some online tutorials and learning as i go. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You UPDATE query updates whole table you should use WHERE statement in this query to update the row 
with current ID

```
update Customer 
set firstName = @firstName, 
    surname = @surname, 
    email = @email, 
    phonenumber = @phone, 
    mobileNumber = @mobile
WHERE ID=@ID
```

Comment: Thanks for that its now updating row [0] but i can have a play about and see if i can get it working. Thanks again